# How to keep showing email verification div with local storage jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, local-storage, session-cookies

Suppose you have a form that consists of two separate divs. The first div is for customer registration, and the second div is for OTP verification. I want to address two issues:

1. If the user enters their registration details but decides to complete the OTP verification later, and then refreshes the page, the second div should still be shown for one hour.
2. If the user has already entered their registration details but has not yet verified their OTP, you want to know how the unverified registration data can be stored.

As the rule to ask question I have to add code but my code is long so I haven't added here. Little guidance will be helpful.

when data is stored after getting success response I hide registeration div by adding class and add otp verification form

Comment: FYI: You don't need to include all your code, just a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will do

Comment: *and then refreshes the page* - at the point of refresh, *read* localStorage.   *for one hour* - use setTimeout.   The timeout based on when either when the entered details (again, stored in localStorage) or 1 hour after page refresh.   *how unverified data is stored* - how do you store verified data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Reyno please check i have add js code when data is insert and after getting success response

Answer (score 2):

To address the first issue, you can use browser storage, such as session storage or local storage, to store a flag indicating that the user has completed the registration but not the OTP verification. When the page is refreshed, you can check for this flag and show the second div if it's still within the one-hour timeframe.

To address the second issue, you can use browser storage again to store the unverified registration data. When the user completes the OTP verification, you can retrieve the stored data and process it accordingly.

```js
// Store flag indicating registration without OTP verification
sessionStorage.setItem('registrationWithoutOTP', true);

// Store unverified registration data
const registrationData = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'johndoe@example.com',
  // Other registration details
};
sessionStorage.setItem('unverifiedRegistrationData', JSON.stringify(registrationData));

// Retrieve flag and data
const hasRegistrationWithoutOTP = sessionStorage.getItem('registrationWithoutOTP') === 'true';
const unverifiedRegistrationData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('unverifiedRegistrationData'));
```